# Some `BigDecimal` values don't match with `Float`

Tags: ruby, rspec, floating-point

Some `BigDecimal` values can be compared with a `Float` by `eq` in Rspec3, but some values can't be.

```
describe "compare BigDecimal with Float" do
    it { expect("83.79".to_d).to eq(83.79) } # => fail
    it { expect("83.75".to_d).to eq(83.75) } # => succeed
end
```

To avoid error, I'm using expressions like `eq("83.79".to_d)`.

Why does the first test fail while the second succeeds?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the canonical ["floating point is broken"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/479863) question due to the presence of Ruby's BigDecimal and RSpec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never try any sort of strict equality testing with floating point values. You always have to deal with inaccurate internal representation issues with `Float`, so `==` and `!=` aren't terribly useful.

Consider this:

```
'83.79'.to_d - 83.79
# => #<BigDecimal:7ff33fcea560,'-0.1E-13',9(36)> 
'83.75'.to_d - 83.75
# => #<BigDecimal:7ff33fcee688,'0.0',9(27)>
```

Note that the difference for `83.79` is not quite zero.

If you need to compare floating point values, you always need to use a delta in your comparison; you always want to say:

> Are these values within some small amount from each other?

rather than

> Are these values equal?

In Rspec terms:

```
expect('83.75'.to_d).to be_within(1e-12).of(83.75)
expect('83.79'.to_d).to be_within(1e-12).of(83.79)
```

and choose the delta (`1e-12` in this case) to match your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

"83.79".to_d is representing the fraction 8379/100 exactly in internal representation because it uses a base 10 (or a power of it), while "83.79".to_f is not because internal representation uses a base 2, so these are not equal.

That's not the same for 83.75 because is is represented exactly in both base 2 and 10 (this is 83 + 1/2 + 1/4).

If you mix big decimals and floats in the same expression, floats are then converted to the nearest big decimal... Thus, you are in fact performing this: `83.79.to_d` or put differently `"83.79".to_f.to_d`
Since `"83.79".to_f` is not exact, and since big decimal is more accurate than float, there's no reason that it matches `"83.79".to_d`.

However, if you force the conversion the other way, I would expect that equality holds:

```
expect("83.79".to_d.to_f).to eq(83.79)
```

This is because we can reasonnably expect (least astonishment) that conversions to_f will answer the nearest floating point to the exact fraction, be it from an exact big decimal or a string representation.

Comment: "big decimal is more accurate than float" – in fact, there are infinitely many `BigDecimal`s but only 2**64 `Float`s, so there are infinitely many more `BigDecimal`s than there are `Float`s.